# What Patterns are useful to know in terms of solving problems or designing better?

Tags: design-patterns

I think patters like Façade, Adapter, Wrapper, Bridge etc describes the  way these things would be done anyway.

Singleton or Factory I think are trivial - most of us would figure out ourselves when appropriate.

MVC is useful, but it usually used through a framework, it is not so often used directly.

**So what patterns are non-trivial and useful in helping us solve problems better, or make better designs (by using the pattern directly)?**

Observer is usually server on a plate, but knowing it can make it easier to think of it when it is not.

I am currently struggling with the Visitor pattern, which seems to be a non-trivial, and helps with design.

---

It is of course useful to know patterns like Singleton and MVC  for other reasons.
If you know the Singleton Design Pattern, you can communicate better and do it in the standard way, so that the code is easier to understand.

Also you can read up on issues about it, and thus code better.

Likewise knowing MVC can make you design better, even if you are not using MVC.

The above reasons are outside the question.

The background for this question is that I often see jobspecs with *"Having used Patterns"*.
Not that I should respond literally, but it make me think.  I can't really say I use patterns just because what i do can be called a Wrapper  or Bridge, or because I use a GUI framework using Observer or MVC.

Comment: I think a book like Design Patterns is definitely worth reading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: Best book for understanding and learning patterns is Head First Design Patterns http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do later you can read original book by GoF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply Head First Design Patterns strategy for learning patterns. First understand the USE and limitations, then the actual pattern.

1) Factory and Abstract Factory

2) Builder

3) Template

4) Null Object but prefer **Google Guice** library `Optional`

5) Factory Method

are some that are useful for making clean designs

**DO NOT OVERUSE PATTERNS TOO EARLY. BUILD SOLID GRIP ON PRINCIPLES FIRST. AND THEN ALL PATTERNS WILL COME NATURALLY.**

Comment: Using these makes design extensible and cleaner. Closed for modification and open for extension, which singleton and some others do not allow.

Comment: Factory is essentially writing a method which is a constructor. I think most developers would come up with that when appropriate.

Comment: @Olav if you are talking about factory methods, then they have their own advantages. More readability, verbose and that is much better than having multiple constructors with confusing arguments. I have also mentioned Builder here.

Comment: @NarendraPathai btw Head First book provides patterns in such order: Strategy, Observer, Decorator, (Abstract)Factory, Singleton, Command, Adapter, Template Method, Iterator, State, Proxy :) Looks like they considered these patterns as most useful

Comment: @lazyberezovsky that's there! I like the way they make you reach the final design. Its easy to understand for newbies!!

Comment: Still I think it is trivial in itself. The way it can be used in an interface based design is not - I am not sure where the pattern ends)

Comment: Most designs are trivial if you understand them, there is no rocket science in them. patterns are just some nuggets and tools you should remember while designing your classes. There was a time when I used design patterns but didn't know their name. So it comes naturally as you get experience in OO principles.

Answer (score 2):

Don't stick to some set of patterns to know and use. Apply [*SOLID*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) design principles to your code and do refactoring to remove duplicated code - that is what all design patterns are based on. Also understanding *SOLID* will give you clear vision of what problem each pattern solves. Later you will understand that you already have applied Strategy, Observer, Singleton and Adapter in you system, when solved some problems or removed duplicated code.

When you starting from other side - by learning design patterns first, then it's like [if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail). You definitely will try to apply patterns even when you don't need them really. Also you will apply wrong patterns often.

I ended with *refactoring to patterns* (well, in 90% cases). E.g. I create State or Strategy only when I see annoying duplicated conditional logic (i.e. *problem* which they solve), not because I foresee that my code will evolve and I will require 10 implementations of some algorithm. Otherwise you can overcomplicate your code by adding new useless classes for future: [abuse of Design Patterns in writing a Hello World program](http://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/the-abuse-of-design-patterns-in-writing-a-hello-world-program/)

Comment: but sometimes there is no need to reinvent the wheel. These patterns are formed on top of solid principles. So sometimes we should use them directly. BUT how they work and disadvantages must also be known.

Comment: I think it's better to learn the patterns by reinventing the wheel. The expertise of knowing and applying design patterns is best acquired the 'hard way'. Teaching a junior design patterns doesn't make him more productive, in fact you've just given him the tool to complicate the code.

Comment: @MikeSW I agree. Even I have mentioned in the edited answer that building fundamentals will naturally make you use and understand patterns. knowing limitations is also important.

Comment: @NarendraPathai you need wheel, when you need it. It's good to learn about wheels, but what if you live at north, when snow is everywhere - ski will fit you better :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Good one! I live in India, so no snow :( but looks like it snows where you live! ;)

Comment: @NarendraPathai Well, wheels are still useful here, but yes, it snows right now :) btw take a look on my last link - it's really funny

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the most common mistakes made by a devel who learns about design patterns: thinking they are some recipes that need to be learned. While the designs patterns are ways to solve some problems, most of the time you'll find yourself using them wihtout knowing it.

It is good to read and know about any design pattern you can find and most importantly to understand what problem they solve and when to apply them. Lots of patterns are poorly understood and wrongly applied, just because they exist and they can solve problems doesn't mean that you HAVE TO use them everywhere.

Also, at one given time you're using just a handful of patterns. The best way to learn is just to write as much and as different software as you can, you'll learn all the patterns you need on the way.

Comment: You're right, of course, by saying patterns aren't recipes but still I wouldn't dismiss the importance of being acquainted with the most common patterns. They are tools that *should be known*.

Comment: I agree - but I was trying to exclude these reasons from my question.
Will try to update it